# Choose column to sort in Datatables

Tags: datatables

I am using the table plug-in for jQuery (datatables) and want to specify witch colum to sort.

**table example:**

```
Name | email | year
```

**My table code so far:**

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        'bSortable': false
    }],
    "oLanguage": {
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "",
            "sNext": ""
        }
    },
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [15, 20, 25, -1],
        [15, 20, 25, "All"]
    ],
     "responsive": true

});
```

For the moment it sorts by the name of customer, alltough my sql sorts by year.
How can i overide this in datatable?

Comment: Just add `"order": [2, 'asc']` to the list of your initialization options, since **Year** is your third column (zero-based index is `2`), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32967972/3549014) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option to set initial order for the table.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [ 1, 'asc' ]
});
```

where `1` is the zero-based index of the column to sort. Use `asc` for ascending sorting and `desc` for descending sorting.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/367u4cb1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();

  // Sort immediately with column 2 (at position 1 in the array (base 0). More could be sorted with additional array elements
  oTable.fnSort( [ [1,'asc'] ] );

  // And to sort another column descending (at position 2 in the array (base 0).
  oTable.fnSort( [ [2,'desc'] ] );
} );
```

Comment: added my java code to example, is there a way to add ur code there?